# RestSharp: get authorize code by username and password automatically

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have an API that deals with registered Azure app, so I would like to get the auth_code without letting the user enter email and password to be authorized because I have a user with full permission so whenever the user wants to generate an access token I would like to let the API consumer to be authorized automatically( Pass the credentials by code.)

```
 RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
        restClient.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize");
        RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        restClient.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("MyEmail", "MyPassword");

        IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
```

In the response, it returns an HTML code for Microsoft to login and authorizes the user, so how can I get the code by passing the email and password.

By the way this is the way postman issues a get request:
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=MYURL&response_type=code&state=&client_id=MYCLIENTID&scope=&redirect_uri=MYREDIRECTURL

Comment: That's how the authorize workflow works... the credentials are not accepted via header or  payload.

Comment: I think you need to use `grant_type=password` to get accesstoken by sending the user's credentials... Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

Comment: Do you know from where i got client secret ???

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad